# PHP Imagick compositeImage set position

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, imagick, watermark

I use the Imagick library for Image processing.

I'm using this function: https://php.net/manual/ro/imagick.compositeimage.php

How can I place the second image above the first image in the left corner for example? I'm using this function to add a watermark above all images. But the watermark is centered on all images. I just wat to align it in the bottom-left side of the image.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to edit the width and the height from the function compositeImage (last two parameters).

bool Imagick::compositeImage ( Imagick $composite_object , int $composite , int $x , int $y [, int $channel = Imagick::CHANNEL_ALL ] )

I guess that setGravity might help, but changing the width and the height sent to "compositeImage" did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Gravity` before compositing - [documentation here](https://php.net/manual/ro/imagick.setgravity.php).

```
bool Imagick::setGravity ( int $gravity )
imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTHWEST
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't helped me. I just needed to edit the width and the height that I've sent to compositeImage function.

Comment: The idea of using gravity is that you don't need to know, or calculate, the coordinates.